# Size and Aspect ratio of exported EPS/PDF and embedding in latex documents

Tags: plotting, export

I've tried to produce figures in Mathematica that have a size consistent with the need of a Latex document. Using a resolution of 72dpi I could produce this

[image]

the black box is 8.22cm x 5.08cm in a picture environment while the red box is 8.22cm x 5.08cm for the boundary of a figure generated with Mathematica.

What is wrong?
F

Comment: What code is used to generate the plot?